# Netlify plugin to generate CSP rules on the fly

Tags: performance, node.js

The following code is a Node-based [Netlify plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlify-plugin-csp-generator) to generate `Content-Security-Policy` rules based on inline styles and scripts.

#### Inputs

- `buildDir` - a string for setting the build directory.
- `exclude` - an array of file paths to exclude from processing. (defaults `[]`)
- `policies` - an object of policies in camel case, for example `defaultSrc`.
- `setAllPolicies` - a boolean as to whether to set policies where none exists. (defaults `false`)

### Code

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const globby = require('globby')
const sha256 = require('js-sha256').sha256
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')

module.exports = {
  onPostBuild: async ({ inputs }) => {
    const { buildDir, exclude, policies, setAllPolicies } = inputs
    const mergedPolicies = mergeWithDefaultPolicies(policies)

    const htmlFiles = `${buildDir}/**/**.html`
    const excludeFiles = (exclude || []).map((filePath) => `!${filePath.replace(/^!/, '')}`)
    console.info(`Excluding ${excludeFiles.length} ${excludeFiles.length === 1 ? 'file' : 'files'}`)
    const lookup = [htmlFiles].concat(excludeFiles)
    const paths = await globby(lookup)
    console.info(`Found ${paths.length} HTML ${paths.length === 1 ? 'file' : 'files'}`)

    const file = paths.reduce((final, path) => {
      const file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
      const dom = new JSDOM(file)
      const scripts = generateHashesFromElement(dom, 'script')
      const styles = generateHashesFromElement(dom, 'style')
      const inlineStyles = generateHashesFromStyle(dom, '[style]')
  
      const webPath = path.replace(new RegExp(`^${buildDir}(.*)index\\.html$`), '$1')
      const cspString = buildCSPArray(mergedPolicies, setAllPolicies, {
        scriptSrc: scripts,
        styleSrc: [...styles, ...inlineStyles],
      }).join(' ')
  
      final += `${webPath}\n  Content-Security-Policy: ${cspString}\n`
      return final
    }, [])

    fs.appendFileSync(`${buildDir}/_headers`, file)
    console.info(`Done.  Saved at ${buildDir}/_headers.`)
  },
}

function mergeWithDefaultPolicies (policies) {
  const defaultPolicies = {
    defaultSrc: '',
    childSrc: '',
    connectSrc: '',
    fontSrc: '',
    frameSrc: '',
    imgSrc: '',
    manifestSrc: '',
    mediaSrc: '',
    objectSrc: '',
    prefetchSrc: '',
    scriptSrc: '',
    scriptSrcElem: '',
    scriptSrcAttr: '',
    styleSrc: '',
    styleSrcElem: '',
    styleSrcAttr: '',
    workerSrc: '',
  }

  return {...defaultPolicies, ...policies}
}

function generateHashesFromElement (dom, selector) {
  const hashes = new Set()
  for (const matchedElement of dom.window.document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    if (matchedElement.innerHTML.length) {
      const hash = sha256.arrayBuffer(matchedElement.innerHTML)
      const base64hash = Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64')
      hashes.add(`'sha256-${base64hash}'`)
    }
  }
  return Array.from(hashes)
}

function generateHashesFromStyle (dom, selector) {
  const hashes = new Set()
  for (const matchedElement of dom.window.document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
    if (matchedElement.getAttribute('style').length) {
      const hash = sha256.arrayBuffer(matchedElement.getAttribute('style'))
      const base64hash = Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64')
      hashes.add(`'sha256-${base64hash}'`)
    }
  }
  return Array.from(hashes)
}

function buildCSPArray (allPolicies, setAllPolicies, hashes) {
  const toKebabCase = (string) => string.replace(/([a-z0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase()

  return Object.keys(allPolicies).reduce((csp, key) => {
    if (hashes[key] || allPolicies[key] || setAllPolicies) {
      csp.push(
        hashes[key]
          ? `${toKebabCase(key)} ${hashes[key].join(' ')} ${allPolicies[key]};`
          : `${toKebabCase(key)} ${allPolicies[key]};`
      )
    }
    return csp
  }, [])
}
```

### Queries

- The main query is the two `generateHashesFromElement` and `generateHashesFromElement` functions, which are identical apart from one uses `.innerHTML` and the other uses `.getAttribute('style')`.  If possible, I'd like to refactor these to be more DRY.
- Should `generateHashesFromElement` be a closure?  I initially built it as one, but the above issue forced me to split it up.
- Is this code readable, or should I add comments?
- Is the code efficient, or could I make it faster?  Run times are a thing in Netlify, so I need to optimise this if possible.

Answer (score 3):

> **The main query is the two `generateHashesFromElement` and `generateHashesFromElement` functions, which are identical apart from one uses `.innerHTML` and the other uses `.getAttribute('style')`.  If possible, I'd like to refactor these to be more DRY.**

There are 2 differences: the `if` condition that gets checked, and the generation of the hash inside the `if` block. You can make a general function by passing it one callback, one which maps the element to the value you want to check on it:

```
function generateHashes (dom, selector, getPropertyValue) {
  const hashes = new Set()  
  for (const matchedElement of dom.window.document.querySelectorAll(selector)) {    
    const value = getPropertyValue(matchedElement)
    if (value.length) { 
      const hash = sha256.arrayBuffer(value)
      const base64hash = Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64')   
      hashes.add(`'sha256-${base64hash}'`)  
    }   
  } 
  return Array.from(hashes) 
}
```

Then use it with

```
generateHashes(dom, 'script', element => element.innerHTML)
```

```
generateHashes(dom, '[style]', element => element.getAttribute('style'))
```

> **Is this code readable, or should I add comments?**

It looks pretty good. The `console`s are useful in that they not only inform the user what's currently going on, but they also show the reader of the code the intent of that section. My only significant question while reading was: what's the function signature of `onPostBuild`? Maybe Netlify script-writers know at a glance, but I'm not one of them, and it wasn't immediately obvious what the type of the `inputs` object's values are. You tell us what they are in the question text, but not *in the code*. (But it's probably fine if you document them [elsewhere](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/build-plugins/create-plugins/#inputs) and have a comment pointing to it)

```
  const { buildDir, exclude, policies, setAllPolicies } =
```

A bit of JSDoc describing parameters and a section of example output might help to make things clearer, for `onPostBuild` and for `buildCSPArray`.

> **Is the code efficient?**

Not so much. The main culprit is:

```
const file = paths.reduce((final, path) => {
  const file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
  // do stuff with file
  return final
}, [])
```

`readFileSync` is blocking; the script waits for files to be read one-by-one, and once one is read, it has to finish processing it completely before starting to read the next file. If there are lots of files to be read, this could take a moderate amount of time. Consider processing files in *parallel* rather than in *serial*. To do this, use `fs.promises` and `Promise.all` to wait for each file to finish, probably something like:

```
const processFile = path => (file) => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(file)
    const scripts = generateHashes(dom, 'script', element => element.innerHTML)
    const styles = generateHashes(dom, 'style', element => element.innerHTML)
    const inlineStyles = generateHashes(dom, '[style]'element => element.getAttribute('style'))

    const webPath = path.replace(new RegExp(`^${buildDir}(.*)index\\.html$`), '$1')
    const cspString = buildCSPArray(mergedPolicies, setAllPolicies, {
        scriptSrc: scripts,
        styleSrc: [...styles, ...inlineStyles],
    }).join(' ')
    return { webPath, cspString };
}
const pathsAndCSPs = await Promise.all(
    paths.map(
        path => fs.promises.readFile(path).then(processFile(path))
    )
);
const combinedCSP = pathsAndCSPs
    .map(
        ({ webPath, cspString }) => `${webPath}\n  Content-Security-Policy: ${cspString}`
    )
    .join('\n');
```

Other nitpicks:

- `const sha256 = require('js-sha256').sha256` simplifies to `const { sha256 } = require('js-sha256')`
- Depends on the OS, but make sure that `buildDir` doesn't have any backslashes. Or, if it does have backslashes, make sure that they get [double-escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17863066), else there will be problems when passed to `new RegExp`.
- The code works, but `toKebabCase` requires an input of something in `camelCase`, maybe call it `camelCaseToKebabCase` to be explicit.

**buildCSPArray**: I don't think `reduce` is appropriate when the accumulator being passed through each iteration is the same object. [Here's a discussion by Chrome developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y) on the subject. I'd prefer declaring an array outside, then iterating with `for..of`. Or, even better, given what's going on inside the loop here, you could use `filter` and `map` - also, use `Object.entries` to retrieve both the key and value at once, instead of using `Object.keys` followed by `obj[key]` lookup. In addition, since the left and right side of the string being pushed are the same, and because optional chaining exists, you can construct the string in a much more concise manner:

```
return Object.entries(allPolicies)
    .filter(([key, defaultPolicy]) => hashes[key] || defaultPolicy || setAllPolicies)
    .map(([key, defaultPolicy]) => {
        const policy = `${hashes[key]?.join(' ') || ''} ${defaultPolicy};`;
        return `${camelCaseToKebabCase(key)} ${policy};`
    })
```

Comment: Great review! The function idea for `generateHashesFrom*` is perfect. That initial reduce with `[]` is because I was pushing it to an array and _then_ reducing it down (had some queries about whether I needed to parse existing files).  What's the policy on accepting answers? I assume wait a bit.

Comment: Oops, I misread the indentation, you're right. (I like 4-space indentation for longer scripts, it makes those sorts of mistakes much harder to make) Feel free to wait a while to see if anyone else has ideas

Comment: Question about your `processFile` function.  It needs to access `path` (see `path.replace(blah)`) but I can't see where it gets passed in.  Would `fs.promises.readFile()` also return the path into the promise?

Comment: Mind blank - `path` is there in that `map`, so I've made a closure.

Comment: No, you're right, `path` needs to be passed along. I wanted to put `processFile` in a separate function to clearly separate it from the `Promise.all` and `.map` sections, but it needs an extra variable, so I made `processFile` a HOF instead so it can see the `path`

Comment: Also, I'm afraid [netlify doesn't like the `?.` syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tCK0.png)!  Replaced it with `hashes[key] && hashes[key].join(' ')` etc

Comment: Are there any differences/advantages between `require('js-sha256').sha256` and the Node.js built-in `crypto.createHash('sha256')`?